# Why can't I choose git install folder on Windows?

Tags: msysgit

I installed [git for windows](https://msysgit.github.io/) a couple times before without any problems. However, right now I can't.

Every time I try to install the installer automatically chooses my external HD as the install folder. I never get the chance to change the install folder.

I think it's important to mention I have portable git installed on my external HD, but I don't see why this would stop me from choosing another folder for a new install.

Answer (score 1):

Simply don't use the installer.

Use the [archive msysgit distribution](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/releases) (currently [`PortableGit-1.9.5-preview20141217.7z`](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/releases/download/Git-1.9.5-preview20141217/PortableGit-1.9.5-preview20141217.7z)): unzip it anywhere you want, add it to your `%PATH%` and you are good to go.

I have several versions of Git for Windows "installed" that way.

Comment: That's cool. 
I'll do it.

But isn't this a bug? Shouldn't I report it somewhere?

Comment: @vtr if you can reproduce the issue, you could report it to https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/issues.